# Как при помощи Aquery сделать GET запрос с заголовком?

Tags: android, http, request

Обычно когда делаешь GET запрос при помощи Aquery нужно прописывать callback. В котором мы работаем с полученными данными, в примере на оф сайте указано как сделать запрос с заголовком

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";

AjaxCallback<String> cb = new AjaxCallback<String>();        
cb.url(url).type(String.class).weakHandler(this, "stringCb");

cb.header("Referer", "http://code.google.com/p/android-query/");
cb.header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2");

aq.ajax(cb);
```

Но я не могу понять где calllback
Мне же в ответ приходят данные и где я должен их обрабатывать.

Answer (score 1):

"stringCb" - и есть ваш колбэк. Почитайте внимательней документацию. В AQ аякс колбэк можно указывать ввиде строки с наименованием функции.

Answer (score 0):

```
AjaxCallback<String> cb = new AjaxCallback<String>()  {

    @Override
    public void callback(String url, String html, AjaxStatus status) {
        // здесь
    }

});
cb.url(url).type(String.class).weakHandler(this, "stringCb");

cb.header("Referer", "http://code.google.com/p/android-query/");
cb.header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2");

aq.ajax(cb);
```